# How do I determine the electric charge on two (initially discharged) spheres after an impact with a charged sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, homework-and-exercises

This is the first part of a problem on my book:

> Two identical conducting spheres, initially discharged, of mass $ m = 0.5 \ kg $ come in contact, in consecutive moments, with another sphere, identical to the previous ones, having charge $Q=4.8\times10^{-7}\ C.$ After the contact, they are located at a distance of $3.0\ cm$ apart. Determine the charge of the two spheres after the contact.

Since obviously the total charge must be equal to $ Q$, and the three spheres are exactly alike, I had thought of an equal partition, leading to $ Q_1 = Q_2 =1.2\times10^{-7} \ C$ and $ Q'=2.4\times 10^{-7}C$. But the book's solutions are $Q_1=2.4 \times10^{-7} \ C $ and $Q_2=1.2 \times10^{-7} \ C $. Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it: They come into contact with it consecutively - the first contact leads to them equalizing, so you will have the charge on the initial sphere as $Q' = Q_1$ with $Q' + Q_1 = Q$. Then, the second sphere contacts the inital sphere, and now it equalizes with $Q'$, leading to $Q'' = Q_2$ with $Q'' + Q_2 = Q'$. Since $Q$ is known, this is a system of equations you can easily solve for $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.